# Problem with variable for arcpy.select_analysis whereclause

Tags: python, arcpy, where-clause

I have a problem with the `whereclause` on python for `arcpy.Select_analysis`.

I try to use a variable for condition:

```
for row_stat in rows_stat:               % for calculated the variable"maxi"
    maxi= row_stat.MAX_GRID_CODE         % for calculated the variable"maxi"
del rows_stat                            % for calculated the variable"maxi"
where = '"GRID_CODE" = maxi'             % whereclause
arcpy.Select_analysis("point_acc.shp", "point_max.shp", where)
```

Ofcourse, I get an error message telling me that 'maxi' can't be found in "point_acc.shp" but I don't want 'maxi' but the number in the variable maxi!

Who can help me write this?

Comment: Could you please add more context?  For example, what are you iterating and why in the `for` loop?

Comment: with the 'for' ,  I am iterating a number (reel double) contain in an other table. I use that to find the Value Max in this other table.

Comment: Looking at the logic of this code the for loop will constantly overwrite the `maxi` value. Is this what you want (unless your table is a table of 1 row)?  If not then you need to test is `MAX_GRID_CODE` is greater than the `maxi` value.

Comment: yes this table have only 1 row. It contains the value maximum of a shape producted after a arcpy.Statistics_analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `maxi` in as part of a string instead of as a variable, so the SQL statement always ends up being `"GRID_CODE" = maxi` instead of variable, e.g. `"GRID_CODE" = 500` when `maxi = 500`.

Instead, use:

```
where = '"GRID_CODE" = {}'.format(maxi)
```

This inserts whatever value `maxi` is holding into the string, and your SQL should then correctly select.

Comment: Finally I have still a problem when I use your code. The problem is: `ValueError: zero length field name in format` 
But when i ask to print my variable `maxi` i have the right numeric value.

Comment: Try `maxi.getOutput(0)`; if that doesn't work, then you may need to ask a new question with a more complete snippet of your current code.